# \setmathfont inside ExplSyntax: successfully compiled but with different result

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, unicode-math

Consider the following example (to compile with LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular.otf}
\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
  [
    range = { it / { Latin, latin }, bfit / { Latin, latin }, up / num, bfup / num }
  ]

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\( f \overline{f} \)

\end{document}
```

The placement of `\overline` does not look correct:

[image]

However, if one comments out `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`, the result looks good:

[image]

With XeLaTeX, the result is still different with or without ExplSyntax, but the result looks even better when it is inside ExplSyntax:

[image]

Since I'm putting the `\setmathfont` inside an ExplClass, does this mean that I have to manually put a `\ExplSyntaxOff` and `\ExplSyntaxOn` around my code? Also, is there some way to achieve the effect under XeLaTeX when using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: There is a warning `Package unicode-math Warning: I am trying to set up alphabet "it/ Latin, latin" but there are no configuration settings for it.` indicating that spaces are not being removed after `it` in `it / { Latin, latin }`, so the output with `\ExplSyntaxOn` is the correct one.  Though I don't know if this is a bug when parsing the keys or if it's by design.

Comment: It is actually the space before `Latin` inside the braces that is (unintentionally, I'd say) preserved.  Replacing `\exp_not:V \l__um_tmpb_tl` near the end of the definition of `\__um_mathalph_decl:nF` by `\exp_args:NV \clist_use:nn \l__um_tmpb_tl { , }` fixes the issue by trimming spaces around the items in the braces.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, it is good to know that the problem is not about ExplSyntax, maybe tomorrow I shall open a new question asking if there is some LuaTeX magic that can fix the over-line placement issue here.

Comment: Well, the output _with_ `\ExplSyntaxOn` is the correct one on both engines, but there is (obviously) some difference in rendering.  Unfortunately I'm basically illiterate when it comes to fonts, so I can't help you there.